# List of halakhos that are only relevant in the era of Moshiach

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, halacha-theory, messiah, tosfot

In [Zevachim 45a (s.v. הלכתא למשיחא)](https://www.sefaria.org/Zevachim.45a.1?lang=bi&with=Tosafot&lang2=en), Tosfos provides a list of instances in Shas where the gemara rules in favour of a particular halakhic position that will only be practically relevant in the era of Moshiach. Adding the passage to which this Tosfos is responding (on Zevachim 44b-45a), is this an exhaustive list? Are there places in gemara where we have a point of practical Moshiach-era law that is *not* mentioned in this Tosfos?

Comment: What do you mean by “the era of Moshiach”? Rambam is pretty clear in the Mishneh Torah, Laws of Kings & Their Wars, chapters 11 & 12, that we will be doing all the mitzvot in the most complete way (like they are found in the Mishneh Torah). That analysis is also brought in Aruch HaShulchan HaAtid. Perhaps you are referring to the transition that will happen from following the view of Beit Hillel for that of Beit Shammai?